# HTML-CSS How to bind element to the right of another one? E.g INPUT BUTTON (LEFT) - INPUT TEXT OR ANY OTHER (RIGHT)

Tags: css

How to create a responsive UI consisting of text and button?  E.g INPUT BUTTON (LEFT) - INPUT TEXT OR ANY OTHER (RIGHT)

Answer (score 2):

Use css flex

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="Test Button" id="test">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
</div>
```

Comment: I have already tried everything, but element doesn't move with any settings apart from top ,left and right params. bottom isn't working either

Comment: This is another question, you can set padding for their parent or themselves. And if you use (position: absolute;) remove it.

Comment: I already solved the problem. Problem was in the specific class i specified in css file for my button. Anyways thanks for help :-)